# Reversing orientation of polygon rings in GDAL/C#?

Tags: gdal, c#

I have a shapefile containing only one polygon. I can visualize this file in QGIS without a problem. However when opening this file with C#/GDAL, I cannot create a SqlGeography out of that polygon feature.

I figured out that this is because this polygon has wrong orientation. I wrote code to reverse the geometry's orientation but I feel my inadequate knowledge of GDAL/C# is making me miss a simpler way to achieve orientation reversal.

How do I reverse the orientation of (rings of?) a polygon using C# bindings of GDAL?

---

Below is the code I wrote to get the orientation reversed. This code doesn't give me the desired result. The line where I add a `reversedRing` to `reversedGeometry` throws an exception about adding a ring that is not *Linear Geometry*.

```
private static Feature ReverseOrientationForGeometryOf(Feature feature)
{
    //Step - 1: Get the original feature's geometry.
    var geometry = feature.GetGeometryRef();

    //Step - 2: Create a blank geometry.
    var reversedGeometry = new Geometry(geometry.GetGeometryType());
    reversedGeometry.AssignSpatialReference(geometry.GetSpatialReference());

    //Step - 3: Iterate over all the geometries in the original geoemtry.
    for (var geomIndex = 0; geomIndex < geometry.GetGeometryCount(); geomIndex++)
    {
        //The first geometry, i.e. the 0th geometry is outer ring. 1st and onwards are inner rings.

        //Get the ring at this index.
        var ring = geometry.GetGeometryRef(geomIndex);

        //Reverse the ring.
        var reversedRing = Reverse(ring);

        //Add revered ring to the blank geommetry created above in Step - 2.
        reversedGeometry.AddGeometry(reversedRing); //!!THROWS EXCEPTION
    }

    //Step - 4: Now set the reversed geom as the geometry of the input feature.
    feature.SetGeometry(reversedGeometry);
    return feature;
}

private static Geometry Reverse(Geometry ring)
{
    var reversedRing = new Geometry(ring.GetGeometryType());
    reversedRing.AssignSpatialReference(ring.GetSpatialReference());
    var point = new double[3];
    for (var pointIndex = ring.GetPointCount() - 1; pointIndex >= 0; pointIndex--)
    {
        ring.GetPoint(pointIndex, point);
        reversedRing.AddPoint_2D(point[0], point[1]);
    }
    return reversedRing;
}
```

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to contain your best effort to extract coordinate arrays from rings, flip the ring order, place it back in the geometry. Other libraries have functions to extract ring vertices in a specific order, or to repair order.

Comment: You add rings to a polygon, then the geometry is set from the polygon. The reversedGeometry should be a polygon since you pass it to SetGeometry.

Comment: ReorientObject? - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26737862/reverse-orientation-of-points-in-a-multipoligon

Comment: @klewis: It wasn't that straightforward. A polygon may contain a polygon inside it. So it has to be tested if this geometry that I am assuming to be a ring is indeed a ring and not another polygon.

Comment: @T.WayneWhitley: The answer you linked is using only C# geography and geometry libraries. GDAL does not have those simpler method calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing to understand in order to successfully reverse the orientation of rings of a polygon is that polygons are self referencing type of geometry. That means that a polygon ring can within itself contain more polygon rings. Hence to reverse a polygon, we need to iterate over all the rings in that polygon geometry and then reverse them.

A polygon ring reversal can only help when all the rings are wrongly oriented. If a polygon has some rings oriented correctly and others wrongly, it is difficult to know its correct orientation.

The code here is to reverse a polygon whose all rings are wrongly oriented.

---

The end to end functional code is written below. I have tested it with GDAL/C# bindings.

First, a base method to call:

```
public Geometry ReversePolygon(Geometry geometry)
{
    //First close the rings in case they are open.
    geometry.CloseRings();
    //Now do the reversal.
    var reversedGeometry = ReverseOrientationOf(geometry);
    return reversedGeometry;
}
```

Second, the `ReverseOrientationOf()` method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Method to reverse the orientation of rings of a polygon OGR geometry.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="geometry">The geometry to be reversed.</param>
/// <returns>The geometry resulting from the reversal.</returns>
private static Geometry ReverseOrientationOf(Geometry geometry)
{
    //Step - 1: Create a SqlGeometry Buidler, set SRID and begin geometry.
    var builder = new SqlGeometryBuilder();
    builder.SetSrid((int) SpatialReferenceCode.Wgs84);
    //We are beginning a multi-polygon because that's what worked.
    builder.BeginGeometry(OpenGisGeometryType.MultiPolygon);

    //Step - 2: For each geometry in the provided polygon geometry...
    for (var geomIndex = 0; geomIndex < geometry.GetGeometryCount(); geomIndex++)
    {
        //a: Get the geometry - which is essentially a ring of the polygon.
        var geometryOfGeometry = geometry.GetGeometryRef(geomIndex);
        //b: Reverse the geometry and add it to the builder.
        builder.AddReversedPolygon(geometryOfGeometry);
    }

    //Step - 3: End the geometry. Get the builder's geometry and validate it.
    builder.EndGeometry();
    var constructedGeometry = builder.ConstructedGeometry.MakeValid();

    //Step - 4: Get the OGR grometry of this constructed geometry and return it.
    return constructedGeometry.GetAsOgrGeometry();
}
```

Third, the `GetAsOgrGeometry()` method, written at the return statement of the method above:

```
/// <summary>
/// Converts a SqlGeometry to an Ogr Geometry from the Buffer (byte[]) of SqlGeometry.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sqlGeometry">The SqlGeometry to be converted.</param>
/// <returns>The converted Ogr Geometry.</returns>
public static Geometry GetAsOgrGeometry(this SqlGeometry sqlGeometry)
{
    if (sqlGeometry.IsNull) return null;
    var sqlWkb = sqlGeometry.STAsBinary().Buffer;
    return Geometry.CreateFromWkb(sqlWkb);
}
```

Fourth, the `AddReversedPolygon()` method which is called in the foreach loop of the second method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Method to reverse and add a geometry to the Geometry builder.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="builder">The builder to add the reversed geometry to.</param>
/// <param name="geometry">The geometry to be reversed and added.</param>
public static void AddReversedPolygon(this IGeometrySink builder, Geometry geometry)
{
    //Polygon Geometries have a tree like structure. A geometry may have children 
    //geometries under it. Presence of children geometries implies that this geometry will 
    //have no points. So, there is nothing to reverse here. Instead, traverse recursively 
    //over its children and reverse them.
    if (IsLeaf(geometry))
    {
        //Now, this is a leaf geometry. So we reverse this.
        ReversePolygon(builder, geometry);
    }
    else
    {
        //There are no points in this geometry, therefore this geometry contains sub-
        //geometries which need to be reversed and handled one by one. This code is
        // recursive. Its recursion is hidden in the ReverseChildrenForGeometry() call .
        ReverseChildrenForGeometry(builder, geometry);
    }
}
```

Fifth, the `IsLeaf()` method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Method to find if a geometry is a leaf geometry and therefore devoid of children
/// geometries.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="geometry">Geometry to be tested.</param>
/// <returns>True or False depending upon children count.</returns>
private static bool IsLeaf(Geometry geometry)
{
    return geometry.GetPointCount() != 0;
}
```

Sixth, the `ReversePolygon()` method. This is the place where we actually do the ring reversal:

```
/// <summary>
/// Method to reverse a leaf geometry and add to the builder.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="builder">The builder to add the reversed geometry to.</param>
/// <param name="geometry">The leaf geometry to be reversed.</param>
private static void ReversePolygon(IGeometrySink builder, Geometry geometry)
{
    //Begin a Polygon Geometry and starting from the last index, add points.
    var lastIndex = geometry.GetPointCount() - 1;
    builder.BeginGeometry(OpenGisGeometryType.Polygon);
    var point = new double[3];
    geometry.GetPoint(lastIndex, point);
    builder.BeginFigure(point[0], point[1], null, null);
    //Go from last point to the 0th point.
    for (var currentPointIndex = lastIndex - 1; currentPointIndex >= 0; currentPointIndex--)
    {
        geometry.GetPoint(currentPointIndex, point);
        builder.AddLine(point[0], point[1], null, null);
    }
    builder.EndFigure();
    builder.EndGeometry();
}
```

Seventh and final, the `ReverseChildrenForGeometry()` method. This method actually does the recursion and goes down until it reaches the leaves of the *polygon tree*:

```
/// <summary>
/// Method to reverse and add all children geometries for the given geometry.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="builder">The builder to add geometries to.</param>
/// <param name="geometry">The geometry whose children are to be reversed.</param>
private static void ReverseChildrenForGeometry(IGeometrySink builder, Geometry geometry)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < geometry.GetGeometryCount(); i++)
    {
        var subGeometry = geometry.GetGeometryRef(i);
        builder.AddReversedPolygon(subGeometry);
    }
}
```